# How do evaluate a recommendation engine using content-based where users information is not given

Tags: python

I am building a recommendation engine using IMDB movie data. In this there is no any information about users. So we need to use content-based filtering. The recommendation will be based on item (movie) item similarities. But how will we evaluate this engine? Here there is no label so we can not use RMSE and pression recall.

Comment: The data set can be downloaded from  https://www.kaggle.com/suchitgupta60/imdb-data

Comment: If I understand correctly, you´re concerned on how to start you recommendation engine when you don´t have any users yet. This is known as the "cold start" problem. Try to read a few references about this.

Comment: ya right sir.Can we do recommendation based on movie contents(features).For a particular movie as a input ,our model will recommend top k movies ,decreasing order in similarity of the features? If it is so then here,does the  evaluation of this model make sense?

Comment: Please try to describe your problem a bit more detailed on the question. For example, what are you considereing as features? What features are you using from the client profile to generate a content-based recommendation?

Comment: Above I have given a link for imdb data set.In that I am considering everything except director name,acor 1 name ,actor 2 name ,actor 3 name ,plot_keyword and movie_imdb_link as features.what I did, I have converted all the object into numeric .